# Create a stored procedure that combines two tables result as one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The code below works well but displays the results in two different tables. I would like to display the stored procedure result in one table.

```sql
USE [LSM2]
GO

-- StoredProcedure [dbo].[Proc_TotalBooks]

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_TotalBooks]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT([Book ID]) AS TotalBooks FROM BookRegistration;
    SELECT COUNT([Book ID]) AS BorrowedBooks FROM Borrowing;    
END
```

[image]

Comment: What do you want the result to look like?

Comment: hello phil, i gave a link up there can you see it?? its an image link of what i want

Comment: That doesn't tell me what you want the result of this stored procedure to look like

Comment: I suggest you read up on how to return data from stored procedures ~ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: i want total books and borrowed book to appear next to totalbooks ie

Comment: i want this     TOTALBOOK.......next to it BORROWEDBOOKS..... if i call this procedure in Visual studio in Gridview it only displays Total book and Leaves out Borrowed books but i want both fields

Comment: select (SELECT COUNT([Book ID]) AS TotalBooks FROM BookRegistration ),(SELECT COUNT([Book ID]) AS BorrowedBooks FROM Borrowing)

Comment: BehrouzMoslem,,,, thanks Bro it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using variables

your query would look like this

```
declare @A int
declare @B int

SELECT @A = COUNT([Book ID])  FROM BookRegistration; 
SELECT @B =COUNT([Book ID]) FROM Borrowing; 

SELECT @A AS TotalBooks, @B   AS BorrowedBooks
```

OR you can use **FULL JOIN**

```
SELECT COUNT(A.[Book ID]) AS TotalBooks, COUNT(B.[Book ID]) AS BorrowedBooks 
FROM BookRegistration A FULL JOIN BorrowedBooks B 
ON 1=2
```

Comment: its refusing both methods

Comment: so far this works but it doesnt show column name .................       select (SELECT COUNT([Book ID]) AS TotalBooks FROM BookRegistration ),(SELECT COUNT([Book ID]) AS BorrowedBooks FROM Borrowing)

Answer (score 0):

I think it might help you : Two values displaying with Description.If you want you can use into Clause to create a new table also

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_TotalBooks]
            AS
            BEGIN
                SELECT 'Total Books' as Description,COUNT([Book ID]) AS TotalBooks  FROM BookRegistration;
            union all
                SELECT 'BorrowedBooks' as Description,COUNT([Book ID]) AS BorrowedBooks FROM Borrowing;    
            END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all`:

```
SELECT 'TotalBooks', COUNT([Book ID]) AS total
FROM BookRegistration
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Borrowed', COUNT([Book ID])
FROM Borrowing;
```

This produces two rows.

Or nested subqueries for two columns:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT([Book ID]) FROM BookRegistration) as TotalBooks,
       (SELECT COUNT([Book ID]) FROM Borrowing) as BorrowedBooks;
```

Or move the conditions to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT t.TotalBooks, b.BorrowedBooks
FROM (SELECT COUNT([Book ID]) AS TotalBooks FROM BookRegistration
     ) t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT([Book ID]) AS BorrowedBooks FROM Borrowing
     ) b  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

select (SELECT COUNT([Book ID])  FROM BookRegistration ) AS TotalBooks,(SELECT COUNT([Book ID])  FROM Borrowing) AS BorrowedBooks